# AC power (220 V / 50 Hz) track width calculation

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, power-electronics, kicad

[image]

I want to control a 5 KVA heater with an ATmega2560. So, I isolated my heater using a MOC3020 optocoupler and a triac (BTA24).

I am confused about designing a PCB for the power circuitry part. How do I calculate the width of the AC supply track?

[image]

Comment: how does your 40W heat-sink attach?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for calculating allowable current through a trace is published in the IPC-2221 standard section 6.2 and you may find [this on-line calculator](https://www.7pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.php) helpful. Best to check with another source before deciding on a value to use ...

Comment: IPC-2221 for current calculators has been superceeded by IPC-2152. All calculators based upon IPC-2221 have been OBSOLETE For over a decade

Comment: heater rating is 5KVA----max current =22.72 Amp

Comment: according to that current internal trace width 28.47mm. it is so wide.

Comment: Yes it could be that wide, But what did you expect otherwise ? What do other PCB manufacturers say ? You can make the board with 2 or 3 oz copper to make a thicker track and so reduce the track width if this is a problem ...

Comment: If it is a two layer board, you could draw shapes on top and bottom layer, use multiple vias to connect and also you can for 2 oz or 3oz copper thickness.

Answer (score 1):

IPC-2152 is preferred for trace width calculation.  It's still not ideal but it's more representative than -2221.  A calculator can be found here (unaffiliated): https://www.smps.us/pcb-calculator.html

Note that there are options for inner planes.  The heat transferred from surface traces to inner planes is quite significant.  I've seen, for example, undersized traces crossing a multilayer board, which failed the UL 5x overcurrent test, in exactly the places where inner planes were absent under the trace.  Widening the trace, and growing the planes, solved that easily.

Doubling up traces on top and bottom, using pours instead of traces (greater width, more free-form shape), and using heavier copper (2 and 3oz are readily available from proto services) are all viable options.  Using a multilayer board is a more expensive option, but can contain even more copper (say 4 layers of 2oz each), and the inner layers can be paralleled up.